# Expiration time makes error in caching

Tags: php, caching, yii

I'm using file caching (CFileCache) to show a simple message from a database table.
When page load for the first time it works correct but when I reload page it makes an Error as: 
include(CTimestampBehavior.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

And This error remains until TIME EXPIRATION which I set in cache->set() and next page load just one time and it makes error again and so on.

Here is my method to handle caching:

```
public static function getLatest()
    {

        //see if it is in the cache, if so, just return it
        if( ($cache=Yii::app()->cache)!==null)
        {

            $key='TrackStar.ProjectListing.SystemMessage';
            if(($sysMessage=$cache->get($key))!==false)
            return $sysMessage;
        }
        //The system message was either not found in the cache, or
        //there is no cache component defined for the application
        //retrieve the system message from the database

        $sysMessage = SysMessage::model()->find(array(
        'order'=>'t.update_time DESC',
        ));
        if($sysMessage != null)
        {
            //a valid message was found. Store it in cache for future retrievals
            if(isset($key))
                //$cache->set($key,$sysMessage,300);
                $cache->set($key, $sysMessage, 300, new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT MAX(update_time) FROM tbl_sys_message'));
            return $sysMessage;
        }
        else
        return null;
    }
```

Error occures in this line:

```
if(($sysMessage=$cache->get($key))!==false)
```

I'm new to Yii and caching and have no idea about it.

UPDATE:
behaviors method of AR models:

```
public function behaviors()
        {
            return array(
                'CTimestampBehavior' => array(
                'class' => 'zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior',
                'createAttribute' => 'create_time',
                'updateAttribute' => 'update_time',
                'setUpdateOnCreate' => true,
                ),
            );
        }
```

Comment: Where are you specifying `CTimestampBehavior`?

Comment: I extended CActiveRecord and made an abstract class to add CTimestampBehavior as a behavior (using behaviors() method) to whole AR models.
getLatest() live in one of these models.

Comment: Can you show the behaviors method?

Comment: Ok ,I updated my question with it.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like your issue is either that:

- framework/zii/behaviors/CTimestampBehavior.php is missing
- framework/zii/behaviors/CTimestampBehavior.php doesn't have correct permissions to be read by your server user
- You are using opcode cache (APC?) and there are some issues on that end, (though reports for this seem to be for random occurrences). Try disabling it.
- For some unknown reason Yii doesn't import your zii routes

In any event I suggest trying a workaround of adding "zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior" to your main.php configuration file "import" section. Or simply calling Yii::import('zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior'); in your function. Hopefully that works and you can continue with your work while diving deaper into the issue when you've got the time.

If it doesn't you can investigate the above (and at least people who come here will have more information to work with)

Comment: Thank you. Importing approach worked.It seems Yii base doesn't import zii routes because all zii components works fine in my web app. I don't know how can I check Yii base for zii routes. By the way I'm sure permissions are not issue.